# transient, null recurrent, or positive recurrent prove of even and odd numbers

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Let $\left\{X_{n}\right\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ be a Markov chain with state space $\{0,1,2, \ldots\}$. The transition probabilities are
$$
 p_{0,1}=1, \quad p_{2 n-1,2 n+1}=p, \quad p_{2 n-1,2 n}=1-p, \quad p_{2 n, 2 n+1}=p, \quad p_{2 n, 2 n-2}=1-p \quad \text { for all } n \geq 1
 $$
where $p \in(0,1)$ is some constant. For every $p \in(0,1)$, indicate whether the Markov chain is transient, null recurrent, or positive recurrent. Prove your conclusion. When the Markov chain is positive recurrent, calculate the stationary distribution.

I have an idea that solving this problem by recurrence formula, what I find interesting is that the recurrence relation is different for even numbers and odd numbers. I have no idear about it. Is there anyone who can help me?